# how to determine source of http request in coldfusion-out.log

Tags: security, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

In the last couple of days it appears some malicious code is being executed on my coldfusion server.  I've found this type of entry in the coldfusion-out.log file

08/20 08:47:02 Information [jrpp-6006] - Starting HTTP request {URL='http://32435898:80/c4/b.txt', method='get'}

I'm trying to track down the source of these HTTP requests but don't know where to look.  I've searched all the code for this text and have found nothing, so I suspect it's being injected somewhere.  Are there other log files or ways to determine what cf scripts are executing this http request?

Comment: You could try to activate the connector log, depending on the webserver you are using. https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/enable-verbose-logging-coldfusion-10.html

Comment: This post has some good suggestions.

https://coldfusionsolution.wordpress.com/2014/10/08/coldfusion-server-hacked-or-server-compromised/

Comment: If you believe that the URL is injected, you could also sniff the network communication with [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/).